# Website Print Padding with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know about @media css tag however it looks like no matter what I set the padding, I se no padding in "print" for my website.

I want to set a padding for print so that I want the website to be printed out with a custom page spacing around the text rather then letting the printer/browser "fit" the content with almost no white area around the website.

Any solution(s) is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you take a look at the `@page` rule ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@page

```
@page { 
   margin: 2cm;
}
```

It's from CSS 2 specs, so it's supported by all major browsers (included IE8+).

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you showed some code — it's hard to offer a solution if www can't tell what the problem is. This works fine for me in Safari on a Mac:

```
<style>
@media print {
    body {padding:100px;}
}
</style>
```

Comment: This does not work, this would be the exact sample code I would send.